# How to compare KEYs to VALUEs in maps in C++?

Tags: c++, hashmap, maps

I was given a declaration of HashMap which goes like this:

```
HashMap<String, T*> resources; //given by my professor
```

Provided also was this remove function *void removeResource(T* a)* and the goal of this function is to search the map for parameter (a) and if it finds that parameter, it removes the value and key associated with it from the map.

So what I've did is this:

```
void removeResource(T* a) //function part given by my professor
        {
            //find the resource and remove it from the map

            for (auto it = resources.begin(); it != resources.end(); it++){
                if (resources.at(it) == a)
                    resources.erase(it);
            }
        }
```

The Visual Studios compiler was complaining pointing to *if (resources.at(it) == a)*.

Please help me out on where I've done wrong.

Comment: Hint: you already have the iterator, `it`. What information can you get **directly** from `it`?

Comment: We have no idea what `HashMap` is or what the error/complaint is as you haven't provided either. Help us help you and edit your post and provide that and any other relevant information.

Comment: Have you ever read [any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at)? It is rather clear. Also, erasing invalidates any iterators and references to erased elements (you cannot `erase` element by iterator and just increment the last one).

Comment: To answer Captain Obvlious, this is the error message I've got from VS: Error 22 error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\franm\od\documents\gam531\lab01\scs_emperor\emperor_engine\emperor_engine\resourcemanager.hpp 125 1 Emperor_Engine

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto it = resources.begin(); it != resources.end();) {
     if (it->second == a) {
         it = resources.erase(it);
     }
     else {
         ++it;
     }
}
```